# Custom Array Adapter Returning Blank Screen?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listactivity

I'm still very new to application development, so this is probably a very stupid question but I can't seem to find the right answer (or at least one that I can understand with my very limited knowledge of java).

I'm using a custom ArrayAdapter called ListRow. It works fine with a regular Activity, but not with the ListActivity that I need it to be in for my app to work.

Below is a sample of the code that I'm using. Any help would be greatly appreciated and you'd be helping a ton!

```
 ListView mListview;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ListRow(this, THEME_NAMES, THEME_ICONS));
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}

public class ListRow extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mThemeNames = THEME_NAMES;
    private int[] mThemeIcons = THEME_ICONS;


    public ListRow(Context c, String[] t, int[] i) {
        mContext = c;
        mThemeNames = t;
        mThemeIcons = i;
        mListview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThemeNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View converView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View List;
        if(converView==null){
            List=new View(mContext);
            LayoutInflater mLayoutinflater=getLayoutInflater();
            List=mLayoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        } else {
            List = (View)converView;
        }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)List.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView textView = (TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.text);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThemeIcons[position]);
        textView.setText(mThemeNames[position]);       
        return List;
    }
}
```

And here's the layout I've defined for each list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:id="@+id/image" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/preview" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you can, please use small words with me lol, java has turned out to be hard to understand for me, and also try to explain as much as you can. Thanks in advance!

FIGURED IT OUT!
So I just put you all through a bit of hell. The layout that contains my list items is called list_item, not list_view. However I have learned a lot here so THANK YOU ALL VERY MUCH! I wish there were a way I could help you guys out...

Moral of this question? CHECK YOUR LAYOUT NAMES!!

Comment: this link will help you. it contains code for custom list view [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193741/need-help-for-on-click-listener-for-android-custom-listview

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but as I said I'm very new to java and posting something like that isn't going to help me much since I barely know what I'm looking at... I'll keep looking around for more descriptive examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set The Adapter in this way

```
setListAdapter(new ListRow(this, your_theme_names_array, your_theme_icon_array));
```

You dont need to use ArrayAdapter for this, that is just for Creating a Adapter for an array of String

**EDITED**

The Layout XML does not have the problem i think.

Check the List given below one by one

**Check List**

- Check Whether R.layout.list_view point to the layout you given in the Question.
- Try this for setting adapter setListAdapter(new ListRow(this, String[] { }, int[] { })); it will show you blank screen (If you get the Blank Screen that means either THEME_NAMES or THEME_ICONS is null or their values is null)
- Remove the Line imageView.setImageResource(mThemeIcons[position]); and
      textView.setText(mThemeNames[position]); this will also give u blank screen (If you get blank screen then R.layout.list_view does not contain R.id.image or R.id.text.

Comment: and also remove this line `List=new View(mContext);` from `getView()`

Comment: List = new View(mContext) is required When convertView is null

Comment: no, since he is inflating his View from resource `R.layout.list_view`, so there is no need to make another `View` object.

Comment: I changed it the setListAdapter line as you specified, but now it's just force closing when i open that activity. Logcat showed a Null Pointer Exception

Comment: @Andrew Tell me at which line you get the NullPointerException

Comment: The line its referring to:
com.masturmods.settings.activities.BatteryManager$ListRow.getView(BatteryManager.Java:111)

I'm assuming that number refers to this line (line 111):
imageView.setImageResource(mThemeIcons[position]);

Comment: I can now confirm this, added a blank line and it now says at  com.masturmods.settings.activities.BatteryManager$ListRow.getView(BatteryManager‌​.Java:112)

Comment: Add your layout XML to question I think the problem is there since the line says that imageView is Null

Comment: I added it, but it works fine on the dummy app I made that used a simple Activity and not ListActivity

Comment: Went through your checklist. FC'ed on me when I removed the icons, but not when I removed the labels. Blank screen. Went through all the xml and even some java but couldn't find an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your mListView in your ArrayAdapter in setListAdapter.Only then the contents of your listview will be display in the pattern you have mentioned in customadapter. I cannot see where you have added elements in listview.

Comment: I updated the question with where I assumed it should go, if this is incorrect, please advise where you believe it should go